# Page is not loading when linked is clicked in cypress

Tags: cypress

1. Vist to https://www.binance.com/en.
2. Click on view more markets link.
3. The website is loading properly but when I am clicking on "View more markets" link. **it is giving 
   the below error:**

Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.binance.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:
https://binance.com
A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new superdomain which does not match the origin policy above.
This typically happens in one of three ways:
1. You clicked an  that routed you outside of your application
2. You submitted a form and your server redirected you outside of your application
3. You used a javascript redirect to a page outside of your application
Cypress does not allow you to change superdomains within a single test.
You may need to restructure some of your test code to avoid this problem.
Alternatively you can also disable Chrome Web Security which will turn off this restriction by setting { chromeWebSecurity: false } in 'cypress.json'.https://on.cypress.io/cross-origin-violation"

**The code is below:**

```
   describe('My firs Test',()=> {
    it('load page',()=>{
    cy.visit("https://www.binance.com/en")
    cy.xpath("//a[text()='View more markets']").click();
    cy.wait(50000);
   })

   })
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try in your cypress.json file turning off chromeWebSecurity?

```
{
  "projectId": "online-realestate",
  "viewportWidth": 1200,
  "viewportHeight": 1000,
  "video": false,
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```